# Подсветка строки, а не ячейки

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, строки, hover

Есть таблица

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(225, 226, 231);
    font-family: futura;
}

.hstyle {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;   
}

.secondandmore {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#second {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.calltable tr td {
    /*border-spacing: 10px;*/
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;

    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);

}

.calltable {
    margin-top: 30px;
    /*border-spacing: 40px;*/
    /*border: 2px solid royalblue;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#btns {
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#addoperator {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

#addnewuser {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

#addnewcall {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

.addcall {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 205, 26);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 205, 26);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;   
}

#deleteoperator {
    border: 1px solid rgb(254, 0, 0);
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(254, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;       
}

.checkboxitemuserlist, .checkboxitemuserlisttotalcost {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    display:  flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.leftmenu {
    flex: 1;
    /*text-align: left;*/
    /*background-color: rgb(235, 236, 239);*/
}

.tableblock {
    flex: 2;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.wrapperusers {
    display:  flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}

.leftmenuusers {
    flex: 1;
}

.tableblockusers {
    flex: 2;
}

#alllistusers {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#alllistoperators {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
}


#alllistoperators tr td{
    /*width: 50%;*/
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    /*
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
    */

    border: 2px solid rgb(207, 207, 207);
    background-color: white;    
}

#alllistoperators thead tr th {
    /*width: 50%;*/
    text-align: center;
    
    border: 2px solid rgb(207, 207, 207);
    /*background-color: rgb(99, 106, 116);*/
    /*background-color: rgb(150, 154, 163); */
    /*background-color: rgb(216, 211, 208);*/
    /*background-color: rgb(229, 164, 132);*/
    /*background-color: rgb(165, 198, 177);*/   /*подходит*/
    /*background-color: #D3DCE3;*/
    background-color: rgb(211, 220, 227);
    /*background-color: rgb(202, 222, 246);*/
    /*background-color: rgb(225, 206, 230);*/
    /*background-color: rgb(239, 243, 247);*/
    /*color: white;*/
}

#labeloperatorname, #labelratevalue {
    font-weight: bold;
}


#alllistusers tr td {
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}


#userdurationcalltable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}

#userdurationcalltable tr td {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}



.leftmenuoperators {
    flex: 1;
}

#operatorsdurationcalltable{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;  
}

#operatorsdurationcalltable tr td {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}


#stattable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#stattable tr td {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    /*
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    */
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid royalblue;
    background-color: rgb(202, 203, 209);
}

#calculation {
    text-align: right;
}

.elemcheckbox {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.elemuserlist, .elemoperatorlist {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.centeredblock {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.chooseperiod {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.chooseperiodbegin {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.chooseperiodend {
    display:  flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#beginlocaldate, #endlocaldate {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

/*
#choosedatetimebegin {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}

#chooseduration {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}
*/

#choosedatetimebegin {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;    
}

.labeldatetimebegin {
    width:  305px;
}

.datetimeinput {
    width: 100%-305px;
}

#chooseduration {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.duration {
    width: 424px;
}

.durationinput {
    width: 100%-424px;
}

#inuser {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#labelinuser {
    width: 310px;
}

#selectinuser {
    width: 100%-310px;
}

#outuser {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#labeloutuser {
    width: 310px;
}

#selectoutuser {
    width: 100%-310px;
}

.checkboxitemusertotalcost{
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.checkboxitemusernametotalcost {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

#operatornameblock {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 30%;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#ratevalueblock {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 30%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

#operatorname, #ratevalue {
    width: 100%;
}

#alllistoperators tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#alllistoperators tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {
    background-color: #D5D5D5;
}

#alllistoperators tbody tr td:hover {
    background: rgb(204, 255, 204);
}
```

```html
<div class="tableblock">
  <table id="alllistoperators">
    <!--                
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Оператор    
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Тариф
                    </td>
                </tr>
-->

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Оператор
        </th>
        <th>
          Тариф
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

При

```
#alllistoperators tbody tr td:hover {
    background: rgb(204, 255, 204);
}
```

подсвечивается ячейка, а не строка. При этом

```
#alllistoperators tbody tr:hover {
background: rgb(204, 255, 204);
```

}

не работает. Подскажите как подсветить строку, а не ячейку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо подсветить все ячейки в строке

```
#alllistoperators tbody tr:hover td {
   background: rgb(204, 255, 204);
}
```

Comment: спасибо помогло. А не знаете как быть на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1337884/%d0%a8%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8?  Та программа, которую посоветовали выводит платные шрифты и совсем не похожие на требуемые.

Comment: @alotofquestions угадывать шрифты по виду это к дизайнерам

Comment: а какую-нибудь программу может посоветуете.